# How to check if character is a letter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, character, letter

I am extracting a character in a Javascript string with:

```
var first = str.charAt(0);
```

and I would like to check whether it is a letter. Strangely, it does not seem like such functionality exists in Javascript. At least I cannot find it.

How can I test this?

Comment: Create a number and test against `NaN`? Or just `isNan(first)` I guess.

Comment: @Marc If this character was '-' for example, your test would not indicate that it is a letter...

Comment: Define "letter"? English alpha only, or something else? Do you want to "blacklist" or "whitelist"?

Comment: Good point. I'm no js expert by any means.

Comment: @JVerstry `-` isn't a letter as far as I know.

Comment: Something like in Java (if possible): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29

Comment: @JVerstry not everybody knows Java. Can't you just tell us what characters will be allowed?

Comment: @PeeHaa True, but in the case of a real letter, his test would return false, exactly like if it was '-'. So, the info provided by his test would still be incomplete.

Comment: @PeeHaa Ok, a character as defined in Unicode.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707972/detecting-if-a-character-is-a-letter

Comment: you may want to remove accents & then do a simple [a-z] check. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings

Comment: @JVerstry I added my answer: it addresses the issue of special characters (used, in Spanish, German, French, Italian, & many more)

Comment: This is a great way for testing if a character is a number or not, but not necessarily a letter (due to Unicode, etc). If all you need is to do a numeric digit check, this should work. Though for special cases it may benefit from some checks for characters that may be valid "numbers", like NaN, INF, -INF, 1.0E+2, etc. I'm actually surprised "-" isn't considered a number in JS since the language is so loose. For example, it could be interpreted as "-0" or "0", like how an empty string can be compared against "0".

Comment: I see a lot of people calling JS Java here.  JS and Java are not the same thing, not even close.  One is a essentially a toy, the other is for making websites.

Comment: Please, if you’re reading the answers to this question (or writing one), do consider that there is a whole world outside “a-z”: diacritics, ligatures, non-Latin scripts. Assuming your code will only have to deal with (a subset of) English characters is bad practice and paves the way for broken software in the long term. Note that even in English you may encounter “é”, “ë”, “æ”, “&”, “ﬃ”, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this plugin has the capabilities you seek: http://xregexp.com/plugins/ (github link:   https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp)

With it you can simply match all unicode letters with `\p{L}`.

Read the header of this source file to see which categories it supports: http://xregexp.com/plugins/xregexp-unicode-categories.js

Comment: Have you got experience in using this plugin on projects you worked on? (just wondering how reliable this library is)

Comment: downvoting as this is certainly a poor answer for 2019

Comment: @Peter Could you please link an answer you consider suitable for 2019? I would add a link to it as an edit to my answer as long as the other solution works with all Unicode characters.

Comment: If you don't want to use a plugin and need the solution to work in any version of JavaScript please consider my answer.

Answer (score 215):

I don't believe there is a built-in function for that.  But it's easy enough to write with a regex

```
function isLetter(str) {
  return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i);
}
```

Comment: The code only tests whether the character is one of the basic letter from a to z (very few languages are written using only those letters). This is very different from the Java function that was mentioned.

Comment: You can still use a regex and just add more detail as you need it:

str.match(/[A-Z|a-z|ü|é]/i); //etc

Comment: maybe this is works?  `var char=str.toLowerCase(); return (char.length==1 && char>='a' && char<='z')`

Comment: @YiboYang - nope, went to the jsbin link above, changed it to yours and ran it, and got this:

"is 'u' is a letter? true"
"is 'ü' is a letter? false"
"is 'à' is a letter? false"

With your code.

Comment: It should be noted this doesn't actually return true || false as one might expect. If `str` is a value from a-z it returns that value. Otherwise it returns null. If you need it to return true / false use this.

`isLetter: function (str) {
    if (str.length !== 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },`

Comment: Just refactored it to return true or false: 
`function isLetter(str) {
  return (/^[a-z]{1}$/i).test(str);
}`

Comment: This one worked for me for simple cases of just checking if alphabets. Thanks

Comment: Soooooo the results of this didn't return a true or false value, which is all I cared about... which can be accomplished simply by changing `return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i);` to `return str.length === 1 && !!str.match(/[a-z]/i);`. If this is something you'd like to incorporate into your answer. Upvoted nonetheless.

Comment: disappointing that the bug in this that was pointed out by Shmack hasn't been addressed yet. could some moderator not do this?

Answer (score 170):

With respect to those special characters not being taken into account by simpler checks such as `/[a-zA-Z]/.test(c)`, it can be beneficial to leverage ECMAScript case transformation (`toUpperCase`). It will take into account non-ASCII Unicode character classes of some foreign alphabets.

```
function isLetter(c) {
  return c.toLowerCase() != c.toUpperCase();
}
```

NOTE: this solution will work only for most Latin, Greek, Armenian and Cyrillic scripts. It will NOT work for Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew and most other scripts.

Comment: Clever.  But based on my very limited understand, it doesn't work with alphabets that don't have upper and lower case, like Chinese or Japanese

Comment: great (and clever) code. Works with all Latin based alphabets.

Comment: Personally I love functions like this as it's so much easier to glance at and understand than the regex functions

Comment: brilliant solution.  In case of c = '1a', simply split your string into array and loop, e.g., `            function isLetters(arr) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if(arr[i].toLowerCase() != arr[i].toUpperCase()){
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } `

Comment: "is 'u' is a letter? true"
"is 'ü' is a letter? true"
"is 'à' is a letter? true"

Seems to work! :)

Comment: Clever, but wrong. :) From [Unicode Case Mappings & Names FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html):

Q: Do all scripts have an uppercase and a lowercase?

A: No (...) The vast majority of scripts do not have case distinctions.

Comment: Compared to the solution based on a `/[a-z]/i` pattern, this trick will accept the complete range of Latin characters. Compared to the other solution containing a complete Latin Unicode upper-lower mapping, you save 99.2% in code size. It is misleading to call this solution "wrong", because it depends on your problem. If your scope is the Latin character set, this is a lean and elegant way to solve it.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet the samples you gave,  c = '1a' or 'a1' are not single letters! This algorithm is strictly for single characters.

Comment: This does work for Chinese and Japanese, as they don’t use letters.

Comment: Very cleaver. It works with latin based alphabet and it is very clear. Good job

Answer (score 53):

```
if( char.toUpperCase() != char.toLowerCase() )
```

Will return true only in case of letter

As point out in below comment, if your character is non English, High Ascii or double byte range then you need to add check for code point.

```
if( char.toUpperCase() != char.toLowerCase() || char.codePointAt(0) > 127 )
```

Comment: just to add twopence, if turning it into a function, add a check is it string and enforce the length to be one or make sure length is one. That's to prevent `1a` for example.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend It works because there aren't uppercase and lowercase versions of numbers, punctuation, and other non-alphabetic characters. In other words, the upper and lower case of them will be the same, whereas the upper and lower case of letters will differ. Personally, I like this technique because it's independent of the language (it works with languages with diacritical marks). I haven't run any benchmarks, but I would guess that this is more efficient than building a regex. (But I could be wrong, since regex are amazingly fast.)

Comment: This fails for scripts that don’t discriminate between upper and lower case, like Chinese.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid, We can add code point check say "a".codePointAt(0).toString(16). The code point should be greater than 127.

Comment: @Sumer, why would that help? Just because the code point is above 127 doesn’t mean it’s a letter.

Comment: All symbols are scattered in code point till 128, rest all are charaters. Some logic can be used for that.

Comment: @Sumer, Unicode currently has 248’966 assigned code points. Only 100’520 of them are letters.

Comment: @michael , can you give one example, one Unicode code point that's not a letter

Comment: @Sumer, “¡” (inverted exclamation mark, codepoint 161). It’s a punctuation mark used in Spanish.

Comment: Totally agreed @michael, is there any solution to separate out such symbols? I guess in this case current solution will work for English and other languages where all characters have corresponding capital letters

Comment: @MichaelSchmid Chinese characters are not letters, so returning false for them is right.

Comment: This method fails with small caps (e.g. “ᴀ”).

Comment: This method fails for any unicameral script, such as Hebrew or Arabic (e.g. “ل”). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicase

Comment: to be honest this is not a good answer, because if you start to use ascii, so why don't you just keep doing that. What's the role of uppercase or lowercase here?

Answer (score 35):

ES6 supports unicode-aware regular expressions.

```
RegExp(/^\p{L}/,'u').test(str)
```

This works for all alphabets.

Unfortunately, there is a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361876) (will be fixed in version 78) that prevents this from being used universally. But if you can control your runtime environment and it supports it (e.g. Node.js), this is a straightforward, comprehensive solution.

Atlernatively, [XRegExp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp) provides a polyfill of modern regular expression to all browsers.

Answer (score 11):

How about using ASCII codes?

```js
let n = str.charCodeAt(0);
let strStartsWithALetter = (n >= 65 && n < 91) || (n >= 97 && n < 123);
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the unlikely case that you are processing only English texts. (An assumption that is wrong for almost every system.)

Comment: When characters are easy to read (as is the case here), writing Ascii or Unicode codes (e.g. 65 instead of 'A') is bad practice, because it’s unreadable. See other answers for how to write this properly.

Answer (score 4):

So we got a first character using `charAt()` function then try to match it using regular expression to check if there is a letter lowercased starting from a to z and return its results as a `boolean`

```js
Boolean('#Foo'.charAt(0).match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) // false
Boolean('Foo'.charAt(0).match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) // true
```

Comment: Letter isn't just a to z. English is a rather important language, yes, and even English doesn't ONLY use a to z.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works with **special characters** too, for instance `é`, `è`, `ê`, `ü`, `ö`, `à`

**2 steps:**

1. Remove the accents, based on this answer: [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings)
2. Check if a to z character, using regex or unicode (your choice)

**Live demos of my solution:**

1. [using global functions](http://jsbin.com/naxopikixofe/2/edit?js,console)
2. [using javascript module pattern](http://jsbin.com/foxicoxocita/1/edit?js,console)

**Note**: I posted the solution that uses global functions as it's probably the simplest to understand. But do look into **"javascript module pattern"** if you want better code (cleaner, easier to maintain and extend), see [impressivewebs.com/my-current-javascript-design-pattern](http://www.impressivewebs.com/my-current-javascript-design-pattern) and also [this YouTube video](http://youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg?t=1m26s) (presentation by Paul Irish).

```js
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalap = [
    {'base':'A', 'letters':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'},
    {'base':'AA','letters':'\uA732'},
    {'base':'AE','letters':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
    {'base':'AO','letters':'\uA734'},
    {'base':'AU','letters':'\uA736'},
    {'base':'AV','letters':'\uA738\uA73A'},
    {'base':'AY','letters':'\uA73C'},
    {'base':'B', 'letters':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
    {'base':'C', 'letters':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
    {'base':'D', 'letters':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779'},
    {'base':'DZ','letters':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
    {'base':'Dz','letters':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
    {'base':'E', 'letters':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'},
    {'base':'F', 'letters':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
    {'base':'G', 'letters':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
    {'base':'H', 'letters':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
    {'base':'I', 'letters':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
    {'base':'J', 'letters':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
    {'base':'K', 'letters':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
    {'base':'L', 'letters':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
    {'base':'LJ','letters':'\u01C7'},
    {'base':'Lj','letters':'\u01C8'},
    {'base':'M', 'letters':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'},
    {'base':'N', 'letters':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
    {'base':'NJ','letters':'\u01CA'},
    {'base':'Nj','letters':'\u01CB'},
    {'base':'O', 'letters':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'},
    {'base':'OI','letters':'\u01A2'},
    {'base':'OO','letters':'\uA74E'},
    {'base':'OU','letters':'\u0222'},
    {'base':'OE','letters':'\u008C\u0152'},
    {'base':'oe','letters':'\u009C\u0153'},
    {'base':'P', 'letters':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
    {'base':'Q', 'letters':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
    {'base':'R', 'letters':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
    {'base':'S', 'letters':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
    {'base':'T', 'letters':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
    {'base':'TZ','letters':'\uA728'},
    {'base':'U', 'letters':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
    {'base':'V', 'letters':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
    {'base':'VY','letters':'\uA760'},
    {'base':'W', 'letters':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
    {'base':'X', 'letters':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
    {'base':'Y', 'letters':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
    {'base':'Z', 'letters':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
    {'base':'a', 'letters':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'},
    {'base':'aa','letters':'\uA733'},
    {'base':'ae','letters':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
    {'base':'ao','letters':'\uA735'},
    {'base':'au','letters':'\uA737'},
    {'base':'av','letters':'\uA739\uA73B'},
    {'base':'ay','letters':'\uA73D'},
    {'base':'b', 'letters':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
    {'base':'c', 'letters':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'},
    {'base':'d', 'letters':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
    {'base':'dz','letters':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
    {'base':'e', 'letters':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
    {'base':'f', 'letters':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
    {'base':'g', 'letters':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
    {'base':'h', 'letters':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
    {'base':'hv','letters':'\u0195'},
    {'base':'i', 'letters':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'},
    {'base':'j', 'letters':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
    {'base':'k', 'letters':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
    {'base':'l', 'letters':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
    {'base':'lj','letters':'\u01C9'},
    {'base':'m', 'letters':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
    {'base':'n', 'letters':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
    {'base':'nj','letters':'\u01CC'},
    {'base':'o', 'letters':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'},
    {'base':'oi','letters':'\u01A3'},
    {'base':'ou','letters':'\u0223'},
    {'base':'oo','letters':'\uA74F'},
    {'base':'p','letters':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
    {'base':'q','letters':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
    {'base':'r','letters':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
    {'base':'s','letters':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
    {'base':'t','letters':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
    {'base':'tz','letters':'\uA729'},
    {'base':'u','letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'},
    {'base':'v','letters':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
    {'base':'vy','letters':'\uA761'},
    {'base':'w','letters':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
    {'base':'x','letters':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
    {'base':'y','letters':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
    {'base':'z','letters':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
];

var diacriticsMap = {};
for (var i=0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalap.length; i++){
    var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalap[i].letters.split("");
    for (var j=0; j < letters.length ; j++){
        diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalap[i].base;
    }
}

function removeDiacriticFromChar (char) {
    return diacriticsMap[char] || char; 
}


/*
 *  [1] Remove the accent, based on answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings
 *  [2] Check if a to z character, using regex or unicode (your choice, here using regex)
 *
 */
function isLetter(char) {
  var charWithoutAccent = removeDiacriticFromChar(char);  /* [1] */
  return charWithoutAccent.match(/[a-z]/i);               /* [2] */
}

console.log( "is 'u' is a letter? " + (isLetter('u') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'ü' is a letter? " + (isLetter('ü') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'à' is a letter? " + (isLetter('à') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'ö' is a letter? " + (isLetter('ö') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'ù' is a letter? " + (isLetter('ù') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'é' is a letter? " + (isLetter('é') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'é' is a letter? " + (isLetter('é') ? 'true' : 'false') );
console.log( "is 'ê' is a letter? " + (isLetter('ê') ? 'true' : 'false') );
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to work with Chinese or Japanese characters

Comment: it's like saying the sky is blue

Answer (score 2):

We can check also in simple way as:

```js
function isLetter(char){
    return ( (char >= 'A' &&  char <= 'Z') ||
             (char >= 'a' &&  char <= 'z') );
}


console.log(isLetter("a"));
console.log(isLetter(3));
console.log(isLetter("H"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the short, clear and fast answer, `&&` (priority: 6) evaluates before `||` (priority: 5), so I think you can drop the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works for all Unicode letters and works in all versions of JavaScript:

```
function isLetter(c) {
    if (c.length != 1 || c == '_' || c == '$')
        return false;
    if (c.toUpperCase() != c.toLowerCase())
        return true; // Speed up accepting latin letters
    if (c.charCodeAt(0) < 128)
        return false; // Speed up rejecting non-letter ASCII characters
    try {
        eval("function " + c + "(){}");
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code uses the fact that the first character of a JavaScript identifier must be a Unicode letter or _ or $, and cannot be anything else.

Here are some unit tests for the above function:

```
    assertTrue(isLetter('A'));
    assertTrue(isLetter('a'));
    assertTrue(isLetter('é'));
    assertFalse(isLetter('2'));
    assertFalse(isLetter('_'));
    assertTrue(isLetter('わ'));
```

Comment: Just be aware that your definition of "letter" may not match the one used in the Unicode char database, in which e.g. `U+4E00 CJK Ideograph 4E00` 一, the Chinese numeral 1, is considered a letter and not a digit.

Comment: That's because for all intents and purposes it behaves like a letter. V doesn't stop being a letter despite being sometimes used to mean "five". There are tons of words where 一 is not used for its numeric value. In such words, 一 cannot be replaced by the digit 1 like it normally is in Japanese and frequently in Mandarin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of regex and test() to check if the first character is a letter

```
/^[a-z]/i.test(str.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m posting here because I didn't want to post a new question.
Assuming there aren't any single character declarations in the code, you can eval() the character to cause an error and check the type of the character.
Something like:

```js
function testForLetter(character) {
  try {
    //Variable declarations can't start with digits or operators
    //If no error is thrown check for dollar or underscore. Those are the only nonletter characters that are allowed as identifiers
    eval("let " + character + ";");
    let regExSpecial = /[^\$_]/;
    return regExSpecial.test(character);
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(testForLetter("!")); //returns false;
console.log(testForLetter("5")); //returns false;
console.log(testForLetter("ن")); //returns true;
console.log(testForLetter("_")); //returns false;
```

Comment: If your test returns true for underscores, then it is not useful.

Comment: This introduces a potential security threat of code injection. Use only with care, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using the library [unicode-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unicode-properties?activeTab=readme).
The library supports Unicode version 12. In this example the library returns the [character category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) for a given string. And then checks if the first character of the category equals to 'L' (which obviously stands for letter).

```js
var unicode = require("unicode-properties");
let str = "E";
console.log(unicode.getCategory(str.charCodeAt(0)).charAt(0) === "L"); // True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// to check if the given string contain alphabets    
function isPangram(sentence){
        let lowerCased = sentence.toLowerCase();
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        // traditional for loop can also be used
        for (let char of letters){
            if (!lowerCased.includes(char)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Unicode currently has 128 000 characters covering 135 alphabets. Those 26 are a really small subset of them.

Answer (score -1):

I made a function to do this:

```
var isLetter = function (character) {
  if( (character.charCodeAt() >= 65 && character.charCodeAt() <= 90) || (character.charCodeAt() >= 97 && character.charCodeAt() <= 122) ) {
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

This basically verifies in the ASCII table if the code of the character refers to a Letter.

You can see the ASCII table on this link and compare columns **DEC** (where is the code) and **symbol**: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Note: My function is true only to "simple" letters (things like "Á", "é", "ç", "Ü" it will return false... but if you needed you can adapt this function to de other conditions).

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to know if the character is a letter or not by using a standard builtin function **isNaN** or **Number.isNaN()** from ES6:

```
isNaN('s') // true
isNaN('-') // true
isNaN('32') // false, '32' is converted to the number 32 which is not NaN
```

It retruns true if the given value is not a number, otherwise false.

Comment: Clever, but I'm not sure it's a sufficient answer... Also, Marc suggested this in the comments...

Comment: var sn ="string indijf &";
  var nn = isNaN(sn)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nn;

I am passing numbers or special characters still return true.
can you please add more details answers

Comment: In which alphabet is “-” a letter?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use built in function isNaN , like this:

```js
var char = 'a'; // can try '123', 'abc'
var checkNo =isNaN(char);
console.log(checkNo); // true
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61546897/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*