# Remove all non-lower case characters from string

Tags: javascript, string

I understand that given a string str

```
str.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

will remove all spaces in a string.

How can I remove all characters that are not lower case letters from the string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could:

```
str.replace( /[^a-z]/g, '' );
```

Comment: would `str.match(/[^A-Z]/g, '');` do the same? i'm having a heck of a time with regex in JS =/

Comment: @Lucas The OP is looking to remove all uppercase. You're removing all lowercase

Comment: @Lucas Oops, sorry, you have the `^`

Comment: Thanks! This works just like I wanted it. I will have to wait 10 min before I can accept your answer.

Comment: @Lucas: This is the answer, but I can't accept your answer. I have to wait 8 min.

Comment: This works for English, Indonesian, and Zulu. What about other languages?

Comment: For other languages XRegExp can be used (this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864191/6805143).