# Check first character of a form field is a letter

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, field

I need to be able to check if the first entry in a form field is a character.
Something similar to below (but with the 'magic' replacing 'somethinginhere'.
Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
function Validator() {
    if (document.theForm.Code.value!= "<somethinginhere>") {
        alert("Code needs to start with a letter");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have something similar [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862761/how-to-check-if-character-is-a-letter-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regular Expression like this:

```
function Validator(astring) {
  return  /^[a-zA-Z]/.test(astring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javaScript">
    function Validator() {
    var letters = '/^[A-Za-z]+$/'; 
    var element=document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;

    if (!element.match(letters)) {
        alert("Code needs to start with a letter");
    }
}
    </script>
```