# What type of programming is this?

Tags: function

I just finished taking an entry placement test for computer science as in college. I passed, but missed a bunch of questions in a specific category: variable assignment. I want to make sure I understand this before moving on.

It started out with *easy* things, like "set age equal to age"

int age = 18, pretty simple

But then, it had a question which I had **no clue** how to approach. It went something like...

"Determine if character c is is in alphabet and assign to a variable"

I could easily do that with a function, but the issue is, it gave me **literally a line** to write my entire answer (so about 50 characters max). Here is how the answer box looked:

[image]

My first thought was to do something like

```
in_alphabet = function(c) {
  var alphabet = ["a", "b" ... "z"]
  if(alphabet.indexOf(c) != -1)
      return true;
}
```

But this solution has two issues:

1. How can I set the "c" value when the whole function is equal to in_alphabet?
2. I can't fit this into the small answer box. I am 99% sure they were looking for something else. **Does anybody know what they were looking for? I can't think of a one line solution for this**

Language doesn't matter (although a solution in java/c++ would be preferred). I would appreciate any guidance (doesn't have to be a solution, I just don't even know where to begin)

Answer (score 0):

I copied straight from [How to check if character is a letter in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862761/how-to-check-if-character-is-a-letter-in-javascript)

```
in_alphabet = c.length === 1 && c.match(/[a-z]/i)? str : ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't quite answer my question because it needs to be a one line variable assignment. I can't fit that on the line they provided.

Comment: I made it much better for you

Comment: Assuming we have a variable named str

Answer (score 0):

The question "Determine if character c is is in alphabet and assign to a variable" does not ask you to create a function (although in many languages this would be the best way to do this).

In `R` you could do something like:

```
inAlphabet <- c %in% letters
```

So you can certainly do it in one line in some real-world languages. Note that `letters` is a built-in list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's a VBA solution and returns C in the variable:

```
LetterC = Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", InStr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "C"), 1)
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Many languages have a data type that represents a single character, and they often can be compared using binary operators like `< > <= >=`, wherein the characters are compared numerically.

So something like this should suffice:

```
in_alphabet = c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'
```

And some languages already have built in methods to do things similar to this (e.g., [`Character.isLetter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char))).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `Character.isLetter(c)`
In .NET, `Char.IsLetter(c)`

Perhaps you were being tested on knowledge of basic data types and some of the facilities they provide.