# How to check if a string contains at least 2 letters

Tags: javascript

I need to check if `test` contains at least 2 letters, like `SC`.

```
var test='SC129h';
if (test.containsalphabets atleast 2) {
  alert('success');
}
else {
  alert('condition not satisfied for alphabets');
}
```

Comment: `if (test.length >= 2)`

Comment: please add some examples

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a string `'SC129h'` and you want to check if it contains 2 letters?

Comment: *At least* 2 characters: `test.length >= 2`

Comment: Alphabets are not same as characters.

Comment: Ok didn't see it like... he meant letters...

Comment: `if(str.split(/[A-Z]/).length-1) ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862761/how-to-check-if-character-is-a-letter-in-javascript

Comment: Do the letters have to be next to each other? What about `S6C`, is that valid?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the RegEx pattern:

```
/([A-Za-z])/g
```

And check for the length of the `test` to be more than 2.

```
var test = 'SC129h';
var match = test.match(/([A-Za-z])/g);
if (match && match.length >= 2) {
  alert('success');
}
else {
  alert('condition not satisfied for alphabets');
}
```

**Better Version**

```
var test = 'SC129h';
var match = test.match(/([A-Za-z])/g);
if (match && match[1]) {
  alert('success');
}
else {
  alert('condition not satisfied for alphabets');
}
```

Comment: `.match() ` sometimes returns `null`, which has no length.

Answer (score 3):

Create a regular expression to match all characters in the string that are in the alphabet, and count them.

```
var test = "SC129h";
if((test.match(/[A-Za-z]/g).length || 0) >= 2) {
    alert("success");
}
```

Alternatively, to be more efficient, do a linear search and check the ASCII code. This can avoid scanning the whole string.

```
var test = "SC129h";
var matches = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if((test[i] >= 'a' && test[i] <= 'z') || (test[i] >= 'A' && test[i] <= 'Z')) {
        matches++;
        if(matches > 2) break;
    }
}
if(matches >= 2) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove all non alphabetic characters then checking for the length of the result.

```
'SC129h'.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'').length > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do `var match = /[a-z]{2,}/gi.test(test)` with would return a Boolean